# MySQL сложный запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

уже сломал всю голову, могу вычленить из базы только по какой-то части условий, но все сразу применить в запросе не получает. Господа просьба помочь.Есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно получить таблицу клиентов состоящую из таких колонок:

1. ***petitions.id***(*order by id desc*)
2. ***phone***(*LEFT JOIN users ON petitions.user_id = users.id*)
3. ***status***(*LEFT JOIN petition_status ON petitions.status_id =
   petition_status.id*)
4. ***type***(*LEFT JOIN petition_type ON petitions.type_id =
   petition_type.id*)

дополнительное условие:

1. выбираем только среди значений, где **type_id = 1**
2. **phone** - не должен повторяться
3. **status**(*status_id*) статус последнего обращения где **type_id=1**(совершенный заказ)
4. **status**(*status_id*) статус последнего обращения **любого типа**

**type** - тип последнего обращения этого клиента

Comment: Ну не лечим мы по фотографиям. Делайте fiddle, или выкладывайте CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO с примером данных, показывайте требуемый ответ для этих данных с подробными пояснениями. И указывайте точную версию MySQL.

Comment: А зачем вам четвертое условие, если есть первое?

Comment: четвертое условие показывает, если после совершения заказа клиент обращался еще